# Reading csv file as a table with Dictreader

Tags: python, csv, dictionary

If I have a CSV file which is organized as below:

[image]

I am trying to use Dictreader for csv module:

```
file =  open('file.csv')
csv_file = csv.DictReader(file)
data = {row['model']: row for row in csv_file}
```

I am trying to read this as a dictionary in which there is a separate dictionary for each model and its coefficients like this:

```
{
  first:{a:1,b:2,c:3,d:4},
  second:{a:1,b:2,c:3,d:4},
  third:{a:1,b:2,c:3,d:4},
}
```

But I still have model name in the inner dictionary. How can I remove that?

Comment: When you say that you want the "model name ... remove[d]" are you saying that you want the output as a list, just containing the values? Like this: `"first" : [1,2,3,4],`

Comment: Yes, This output is also acceptable

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can pop the `model` key from each `row` dict instead:

```
data = {row.pop('model'): row for row in csv_file}
```